# ApplicationMailer is making CC to all the receivers from the array.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am trying to send bulk emails to a bunch of receivers. The email is being delivered to the expected receivers but it is CCing all the receivers. I dont't want receivers to be able to see other receivers emails.  I might be doing it wrong. Below is my ruby method in ApplicationMailer.

```
class WantedEquipmentMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def sendmail
       @receiver = WantedEquipment.where(sub_category_id: "#{a}", status: 2).pluck(:email)
       mail(to: @receiver, subject: @subject)
    end
end
```

**Equipment.rb**

```
def email_newequip_matches_wanted
    WantedEquipmentMailer.sendmail.deliver
end
```

What changes should I make so that it wont cc all the receivers stored in that array (@receiver). ?

Comment: Either send out individual mails per user or use BCC field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to something like this which i just pulled from the docs. [Action Mailer classes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

```
class NotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
 default from: 'no-reply@example.com',
      return_path: 'system@example.com'

 def welcome(recipient)
   @account = recipient
  mail(to: recipient.email_address_with_name,
     bcc: ["bcc@example.com", "Order Watcher <watcher@example.com>"])
 end
end
```

Send across the mails with :bcc the way it is done in basic mail clients.

Comment: I changed  `mail(to: @receiver, bcc: ["sender@email.com"], subject: @subject)`. And sent to two users. Both had each other's email CCd. Its not working.

Comment: Ok now its working. I removed `to:` field and passed the `@receiver' to `bcc:` which has more than 2 emails. I want one default email to be able to see all the `bcc` emails. How can I achieve that ?